# How to deal with the mismatched lengths with the .loc function

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

It'll be easier to explain the issue once I post my code.

Here are my first two dfs:

```
df_data1 = {
    "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "Date": ['01-01-2010', '01-02-2010', '01-03-2010', '01-04-2010', '01-05-2010'],
    'Value': [90, 58, 85, 33, 68]
}

df_data2 = {
    "ID": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "Date": ['01-06-2010', '01-07-2010', '01-08-2010', '01-09-2010', '01-10-2010'],
    "Value": [85, 39, 99, 15, 87]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df_data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df_data2)
```

[image]

I then merge these two using the cross method so these two dfs compare line-by-line.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how="cross")
df3
```

[image]

I then make a fourth df with two indexes, so I have a neat df that has each row being how the two compares to one another.

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame()
df4["Value"] = (df3[['Value_x', 'Value_y']].mean(axis=1))
df4.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(itertools.product(df1["ID"], df2["ID"])), names = ['df1 ID', 'df2 ID'])
df4
```

[image]

Now here's where I'm getting into trouble. What I want to do is add columns. One column to show the first index's date and the second to show the second's. I thought loc would be the best tool to use. Here's the code I tried to use:

```
df4['df1 Date'] = df1.loc[df1['Date'] == df4.index.get_level_values(0)]['Date']
df4
```

And here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-253564fdd003> in <module>
----> 1 df4['df1 Date'] = df1.loc[df1['Date'] == df4.index.get_level_values(0)]['Date']
      2 df4

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     68 
---> 69         return method(self, other)
     70 
     71     return new_method

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py in __eq__(self, other)
     30     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__eq__")
     31     def __eq__(self, other):
---> 32         return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
     33 
     34     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__ne__")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)
   5500 
   5501         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 5502             res_values = ops.comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
   5503 
   5504         return self._construct_result(res_values, name=res_name)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    260         if len(lvalues) != len(rvalues):
    261             raise ValueError(
--> 262                 "Lengths must match to compare", lvalues.shape, rvalues.shape
    263             )
    264 

ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (5,), (25,))
```

I get why the error is coming up, but I don't know how to get past it. It misunderstands my intention. I'm not trying to compare 25 rows against 5; I'm trying to show the date from df1 in a new column, whenever that ID shows up in that specific index.

After I fix this issue, I plan on doing the same for the second index, and then ultimately adding a third column that subtracts the two dates so that it can measure the time elapsed between the two dates. If you know of a good, succinct code for that, I'd be helpful too, but I can also do that myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple, avoid the intermediates and `itertools`:

```
out = (df1
 .merge(df2, how='cross', suffixes=['_df1', '_df2'])
 .set_index(['ID_df1', 'ID_df2'])
 .assign(Value=lambda d: d.pop('Value_df1').add(d.pop('Value_df2')).div(2))  
)
```

Alternative:

```
out = (df1
 .merge(df2, how='cross', suffixes=['_df1', '_df2'])
 .set_index(['ID_df1', 'ID_df2'])
 .assign(Value=lambda d: d[['Value_df1', 'Value_df2']].mean(axis=1))
 .drop(columns=['Value_df1', 'Value_df2'])
)
```

*NB. if you really want `df1`/`df2` as prefix and not suffix, `rename` or use a regex to post-process the names.*

Output:

```
                 Date_df1    Date_df2  Value
ID_df1 ID_df2                               
1      6       01-01-2010  01-06-2010   87.5
       7       01-01-2010  01-07-2010   64.5
       8       01-01-2010  01-08-2010   94.5
       9       01-01-2010  01-09-2010   52.5
       10      01-01-2010  01-10-2010   88.5
2      6       01-02-2010  01-06-2010   71.5
       7       01-02-2010  01-07-2010   48.5
       8       01-02-2010  01-08-2010   78.5
       9       01-02-2010  01-09-2010   36.5
       10      01-02-2010  01-10-2010   72.5
3      6       01-03-2010  01-06-2010   85.0
       7       01-03-2010  01-07-2010   62.0
       8       01-03-2010  01-08-2010   92.0
       9       01-03-2010  01-09-2010   50.0
       10      01-03-2010  01-10-2010   86.0
4      6       01-04-2010  01-06-2010   59.0
       7       01-04-2010  01-07-2010   36.0
       8       01-04-2010  01-08-2010   66.0
       9       01-04-2010  01-09-2010   24.0
       10      01-04-2010  01-10-2010   60.0
5      6       01-05-2010  01-06-2010   76.5
       7       01-05-2010  01-07-2010   53.5
       8       01-05-2010  01-08-2010   83.5
       9       01-05-2010  01-09-2010   41.5
       10      01-05-2010  01-10-2010   77.5
```

Comment: I'm having trouble applying this to the actual problem I'm working on. Is there a solution that could apply after the df has already been created?

Comment: After which "df" has been created? Can you be more specific?

Comment: After df4 has already been created. Is there a way I could adjust a loc or replace it with an iloc so I could add in the dates there?

Comment: Yes, you can `join`/`merge` each initial DataFrame. But why do you need to create `df4` manually?

Comment: I don't need to create the df4 manually, but I'm having trouble fitting the examples you had to the df I'm actually working. Just to clarify, are you saying I wouldn't be able to use loc or even iloc as a tool at all because of the error I've faced?

Comment: TBH I don't see what is your issue. Either your example is representative of your real data and use my approach, or it is not and you need to be more explicit